# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d' [Python/OpenCV 2.4]

Tags: python, opencv

This line:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

return error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/openCVskrypty/GUI/SOLUTION2.py", line 11, in <module>
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

I read something about this error and it appears in OpenCV version 3.0. 
This is quite weird because I have 2.4.11 version.

I check dir(cv2) and I haven't got xfeatures2d module. Does anyone know why? Can I download it separately?

Thanks for help how fix this.

Answer (score 66):

I think you should install opencv-contrib-python instead. The module you're using is not support in opencv-python. See [opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python).

To install:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: This is likely the right solution for those using OpenCV 3+ who see the AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

Comment: have you tried to uninstall the previous OpenCV first?

Comment: Worked for me but got this warning - [ WARN:0@0.237] global shadow_sift.hpp:13 SIFT_create DEPRECATED: cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() is deprecated due SIFT tranfer to the main repository. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736

Answer (score 34):

SIFT is a patented algorithm, hence not available in each open-cv version. What you can do is install opencv and its contrib part simultaneously, i.e,

```
pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10 opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.10
```

SIFT worked fine for me on above versions of opencv.

Comment: You can even go up to `3.4.2.17` and still use SIFT.

Comment: At least for me, cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() only work on 3.3.0.10

Comment: ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.3.0.10

Comment: Version 3.3.0.10 wasn't available now, next version up was 3.4.2.16 and was able to work with ```sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()``` .  I also had to do pip3 install opencv-python 

sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev 

sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev 

sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 

sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 

sudo apt install libqt4-test

Comment: Is available in newer versions just by using `cv2.SIFT_create()`. I am using opencv 4.5.4 rn

Answer (score 23):

For CV2 Version 4.5.1, this works

```
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
kp = sift.detect(gimg,None)
img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gimg,kp,img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: https://github.com/HeatherJiaZG/SuperGlue-pytorch/issues/13

Comment: Works for me as well with opencv-python==4.5.3.56 and opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56

Comment: @Usama what is gimg?

Comment: @SyedHussain It is the gray Image.

Answer (score 14):

After executing the command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

, I got the following error:

> error: OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   /Users/rene/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1207:
>   error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm
>   is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set
>   OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function
>   'create'

Could solve it with the following command in anaconda:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Or with pip:

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17

pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

Comment: No matching distribution found

Comment: should be `pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17`

Comment: Do install 3.4.2.16 if you want to use SIFT or SURF. (Tested) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305578/sift-cv2-xfeatures2d-sift-create-not-working-even-though-have-contrib-instal

Answer (score 5):

I got this error and all I did was to uninstall opencv packages and install them in the following order.

**STEPS**

open *`Anaconda Prompt`* by *`running as administrator`* and type the following commands.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python

pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Then type the following commands

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16

pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
```

This solved my problem. Hope this solves yours!!

Answer (score 4):

In latest CV2 Version 4.5.3.56, this works:

```
img1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\CW\Desktop\new_img.png') 
sift = cv2.SIFT_create() 
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I used to have similar problem as @srihegde said you can try to uninstall *opencv-contrib-python* package and reinstall again. You can also try to uninstall *opencv-python* package if you have one, since it might mess with the packages too.

This helped for me.

Uninstall:

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

And then install:

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: I only need the install part:

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error... I have used `cv2.__version__`  and   `cv2.__path__` to check the opencv version and path. Then I removed **cv2** from **site-packages**. and install the following

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17

pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

Comment: This is the order of installation which works for the latest version.

Comment: No matching distribution found

Comment: You have to modify the distribution version of open cv with the latest one. Presently its  4.1.2.30.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sift = cv2.SIFT_create()` instead of `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` as sift patent has expired now, so OpenCV has moved `SIFT_create()` directly to main repository instead of contrib module in versions > 4.4 , [see this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your version of OpenCV. You say you're on version 2.4.11 but this version of OpenCV doesn't have this method available to it.

You can check the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/). It has [features2d](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html?highlight=features2d)

Whereas OpenCV 3.0 does.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I download this module separately whether I have to download v.3.0 OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

This error may also occur in OpenCV 3+ as it is caused by mismatched versions of OpenCV and OpenCV-Contrib package.

I had OpenCV version 3.4.1 and OpenCV-Contrib version 3.4.0. I tried the following with OpenCV-Contrib:

Uninstall  OpenCV-Contrib package:

```
$ pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Then install the same again:

```
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

The pip automatically fetches and installs the latest compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for OpenCV 4.0 due to US patent matter. Perhaps we shall give it a thumb up for this OpenSift effort:

https://github.com/robwhess/opensift

Answer (score 0):

Open a Powershell Prompt and type the following command:

```
pip install --user opencv-contrib-python
```

Fixed it for me.

Open an Ananconda Powershell Prompt if you are using Jupyter Notebook.