# How can I use SIFT in opencv 2.4

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I want to use SIFT. I've already tried this code:

```
  import cv2
  import numpy as np
  img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
  gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
  kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
  img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,img)
  cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
```

But I get this error:

***./sifttt.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('***

***./sifttt.py: line 3: `img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')'***

I don't know if I need to install something or if I need to do something else?

Comment: The error w.r.t. the code doesn't make sense! Are you sure this is the code?

Comment: Run the code as `python sifttt.py`, to check that you are using the correct interpreter, just in case.

Comment: Your code works on my machine. No error. The SIFT points are detected properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code at line number 5. You are using opencv 2.4 version but opencv 2.4 does not have xfeature2d module this module is found in openv 3 in up [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039224/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d-python-opencv-2). So to use Sift in opencv 2.4 use [this](https://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/sift-keypoint-matching-using-python-opencv/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984313/opencv-2-4-1-computing-surf-descriptors-in-python) tutorials.