# I can't install SIFT in OPENCV

Tags: python

I cant use SIFT, when i enter the command 
`sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`
It shows `module has no attribute named xfeatures2d`
Please someone help me, i am in emergency!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039224/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d-python-opencv-2 and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d' \[Python/OpenCV 2.4\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039224/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d-python-opencv-2)

Answer (score 0):

SIFT is a patented algorithm, hence not available in each open-cv version. What you can do is install opencv and its contrib part simultaneously, i.e,

```
pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10 opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.10
```

SIFT worked fine for me on above versions of opencv.